# Parallel distribution of a 2D array

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, multidimensional-array

I need some advice on parallel workload distribution, based on the heat distribution problem, using the Jocobi method. The program works by splitting a 2D array into 4 equally sized grids, via a parallel for - then to further break down each of the smaller grids into row clusters of e.g. 10 rows which are to be processed in new tasks.  The initial grid size is 10000x10000.

The program works but it is significantly slower than my other parallel implementations, e.g. clustering rows, without splitting the 2D array.  Even when using a for loop, there is a lot of lag.  I dont understand why, due to the access time of the array.  For example, calculating: x[5000, 9999] y[5000, 9999] (the bottom, right-hand corner)

Can anyone offer an explanation for the holdup?

```
class ParallelHeatDistribution_QuadCluster
{
    private double[,] heatGrid;
    private int gridDimensions;

    private int x1, x2, x3;
    private int y1, y2, y3;

    private int[,] quadDimensions;

    public ParallelHeatDistribution_QuadCluster(double[,] heatGrid, int gridDimensions)
    {
        this.heatGrid = heatGrid;
        this.gridDimensions = gridDimensions;

        this.x1 = 1;
        this.x2 = this.gridDimensions / 2;

        this.y1 = 1;
        this.y2 = this.gridDimensions / 2;

        this.x3 = this.gridDimensions - 1;
        this.y3 = this.gridDimensions - 1;

        this.quadDimensions = new int[4, 4] {{x1, x2, y1, y2}, {x1, x2, y2, y3}, {x2, x3, y1, y2}, {x2, x3, y2, y3}};
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start parallel distribution
    /// </summary>
    public void parallelDistribution(int clusterRowCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            DistributeWorkload(clusterRowCount, quadDimensions[3, 0], quadDimensions[3, 1], quadDimensions[3, 2], quadDimensions[3, 3]);
        }

        Parallel.For(0, 3, i =>
        {
            //DistributeWorkload(clusterRowCount, quadDimensions[i, 0], quadDimensions[i, 1], quadDimensions[i, 2], quadDimensions[i, 3]);
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate heat distribution in parallel by assigning work to tasks based on x-amount of loop iterations.  Each iteration represents an array row partition
    /// </summary>
    private void DistributeWorkload(int clusterRowCount, int xStartPoint, int xEndpoint, int yStartPoint, int yEndpoint)
    {
        /* calculate data partition cluster for parallel distribution. */
        int clusterCount = (gridDimensions) / clusterRowCount;

        /* Parallel task arrays for black and white elements */
        Task[] taskArray1 = new Task[clusterCount];
        Task[] taskArray2 = new Task[clusterCount];

        try
        {
            /* assign work to for set of tasks calculating the "black squares" */
            int c = 0;
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < clusterCount; x1++)
            {
                int clusterSize = c;
                taskArray1[x1] = new Task(() => setTask(clusterRowCount, clusterSize, true, xStartPoint, xEndpoint, yStartPoint, yEndpoint));
                c = c + clusterRowCount;
            }

            /* assign work to second set of tasks calculating the "white squares" */
            c = 0;
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < clusterCount; x2++)
            {
                int clusterSize = c;
                taskArray2[x2] = new Task(() => setTask(clusterRowCount, clusterSize, false, xStartPoint, xEndpoint, yStartPoint, yEndpoint));
                c = c + clusterRowCount;
            }


            /* start all tasks */
            foreach (Task t in taskArray1) t.Start();
            Task.WaitAll(taskArray1);

            foreach (Task t in taskArray2) t.Start();
            /* and wait... */
            Task.WaitAll(taskArray2);

        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Task: calculate a cluster of rows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="y"> y-axis position </param>
    /// <param name="isFirst"> determine grid element set </param>
    public void setTask(int clusterRowCount, int currentClusterCount, bool isFirst, int xStartPoint, int xEndpoint, int yStartPoint, int yEndpoint)
    {
        int yPos = yStartPoint + currentClusterCount;
        double temperature;

        for (int y = yPos; y < yEndpoint; y++)
        {
            for (int x = xStartPoint; x < xEndpoint; x++)
            {
                if (isFirst && y % 2 == 0 || !isFirst && y % 2 != 0)
                {
                    if (x % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        temperature = (heatGrid[y - 1, x] + heatGrid[y + 1, x] + heatGrid[y, x - 1] + heatGrid[y, x + 1]) / 4;
                        heatGrid[x, y] = temperature;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        temperature = (heatGrid[y - 1, x] + heatGrid[y + 1, x] + heatGrid[y, x - 1] + heatGrid[y, x + 1]) / 4;
                        heatGrid[x, y] = temperature;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many CPU cores does your computer have? If it's 4 (or less), then there is no reason for using the `Task`s in your `Parallel.For()`.

Comment: oh... i am using an i3 at the mo.  but it will be run on an 8 core machine eventually.